# a pushBack() function, as opposite to popFront()

Tags: d

Can I use `popFront()` and then eventually push back what was poped? The number of calls to `popFront()` might be more than one (but not much greater than it, say < 10, if does matter). This is also the number of calls which the imaginary `pushBack()` function will be called too.

for example:

```
string s = "Hello, World!";
int n = 5;
foreach(i; 0 .. n) {
    // do something with s.front
    s.popFront();
}

if(some_condition) {
    foreach(i; 0 .. n) {
        s.pushBack();
    }
}
writeln(s); // should output "Hello, World!" since number of poped is same as pushed back.
```

I think `popFront()` does use `.ptr` but I'm not sure if it in D does makes any difference and can help anyway to reach my goal easily (i.e, in D's way and not write my own with a [Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) or so).

A completely different approach to reach it is very welcome too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A range is either generative (e.g. if it's a list of random numbers), or it's a view into a container. In neither case does it make sense to push anything onto it. As you call `popFront`, you're iterating through the list and shrinking your view of the container. If you think of a range being like two C++ iterators for a moment, and you have something like

```
struct IterRange(T)
{
    @property bool empty() { return iter == end; }
    @property T front() { return *iter; }
    void popFront() { ++iter; }

    private Iterator iter;
    private Iterator end;
}
```

then it will be easier to understand. If you called `popFront`, it would move the iterator forward by one, thereby changing which element you're looking at, but you can't add elements in front of it. That would require doing something like an insertion on the container itself, and maybe the iterator or range could be used to tell the container where you want an alement inserted, but the iterator or range can't do that itself. The same goes if you have a generative range like

```
struct IncRange(T)
{
    @property bool empty() { value == T.max; }
    @property T front() { return value; }
    void popFront() { ++value; }

    private T value;
}
```

It keeps incrementing the value, and there is no container backing it. So, it doesn't even have anywhere that you could push a value onto.

Arrays are a little bit funny because they're ranges but they're also containers (sort of). They have range semantics when popping elements off of them or slicing them, but they don't own their own memory, and once you append to them, you can get a completely different chunk of memory with the same values. So, it is sort of a range that you can add and remove elements from - but you can't do it using the range API. So, you *could* do something like

```
str = newChar ~ str;
```

but that's not terribly efficient. You could make it more efficient by creating a new array at the target size and then filling in its elements rather than concatenating repeatedly, but regardless, pushing something on the the front of an array is not a particularly idiomatic or efficient thing to be doing.

Now, if what you're looking to do is just reset the range so that it once again refers to the elements that were popped off rather than really push elements onto it - that is, open up the window again so that it shows what it showed before - that's a bit different. It's still not supported by the range API at all (you can never unpop anything that was popped off). However, if the range that you're dealing with is a forward range (and arrays are), then you can save the range before you pop off the elements and then use that to restore the previous state. e.g.

```
string s = "Hello, World!";
int n = 5;
auto saved = s.save;
foreach(i; 0 .. n)
    s.popFront();

if(some_condition)
    s = saved;
```

So, you have to explicitly store the previous state yourself in order to restore it instead of having something like `unpopFront`, but having the range store that itself (as would be required for `unpopFront`) would be very inefficient in most cases (much is it might work in the iterator case if the range kept track of where the beginning of the container was).

Comment: Could you explain how is using `.save` property different from `s` itself? from what I learned, `saved = s; ... if(some_condition) s = save` will be fine, they works just like pointers.

Comment: If all you're dealing with is arrays, then `save` is pointless. It'll just return a slice of the same array. However, in the case of general forward ranges, it's quite important, because `save` results in a slice of the range - it refers to the same elements, but altering the range itself doesn't alter the original - and simply assigning the range to a new variable doesn't necessarily do that. It depends on how the range is implemented. So, `save` is necessary for generic range-based code (and most range-based code should be generic).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard way to "unpop" a range or a string.

If you were to pass a slice of a string to a function:

```
fun(s[5..10]);
```

You'd expect that that function would only be able to see those 5 characters. If there was a way to "unpop" the slice, the function would be able to see the entire string.

Now, D is a system programming language, so expanding a slice is possible using pointer arithmetic and GC queries. But there is nothing in the standard library to do this for you.